# Как можно отсортировать map по значениям по убыванию?

Tags: java, map

В итоге должны выводиться пары ключ-значение, например:

```
7 6
5 4
3 1
```

Код:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        int cnt = 0;
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sms = new TreeMap<>();


        int b = 1;
        int k = 1;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            if (sms.containsKey(n)) {
                sms.put(n, k += 1);

            } else {
                sms.put(n, b);
                k = 1;
            }

            cnt++;
            if (cnt == N) {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> abc : sms.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(abc.getKey() + " ");
            System.out.println(abc.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, разве TreeMap не отсортирована по ключу все время?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sms.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
   .map(e -> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Мои пять копеек, в качестве компаратора можно использовать `Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed()`